# How to add buffer to list of function in power query to make it faster

Tags: excel, list, powerquery

I am using the list of position function in Excel PowerQuery, but it is slowing down the query and causing it to run very slow.  I saw online that you can add buffer table to the query to help it run faster, but I haven't gotten any success doing so. Can you please help?  See the code below:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"PROD_CD", type text}, {"People Soft_FIN_ACCT", type text}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Account Index", each List.PositionOf(#"Ledger Account"[Legacy ID],[People Soft_FIN_ACCT])),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "WorkDay Account Number", each #"Ledger Account"[Ledger Account Identifier]{[Account Index]}),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Workday Account Name", each #"Ledger Account"[Ledger Account Name]{[Account Index]}),
#"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Spend Category", each #"Ledger Account"[SC Ref ID]{[Account Index]}),
#"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom3", "Bank Account", each #"Ledger Account"[Bank Account]{[Account Index]}),
#"Added Custom5" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom4", "Distribution Partner", each #"Ledger Account"[Distribution Partner]{[Account Index]}),
#"Added Custom6" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom5", "Classification", each #"Ledger Account"[Classification]{[Account Index]}),
#"Added Custom7" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom6", "Affiliate", each #"Ledger Account"[Affiliate]{[Account Index]})
in #"Added Custom7"
```

I tried to add Table.buffer to the code, but got an error message:

Expression.Error: 2 arguments were passed to a function which expects 1.
Details:
Pattern=
Arguments=[List]

Comment: Did this solution work for you?  If so then pleas upvote and mark as solved

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this, relying on a merge instead of all those indexes

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"PROD_CD", type text}, {"People  Soft_FIN_ACCT", type text}}),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Changed Type", {"People Soft_FIN_ACCT"}, #"Ledger Account", {"Legacy ID"}, "Ledger Account", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Ledger Account" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Ledger Account", {"Distribution Partner", "Ledger Account Name"}, {"Distribution Partner", "Ledger Account Name"})
 in  #"Expanded Ledger Account"
```

[image]